# jquery plugin for displaying names with starting letter

Tags: jquery

I am not able to find a plugin I had used year and a half ago. I have a list of 800 names. I am looking for a jQuery plugin which at the top or on side displays something like

```
A B C D E ...
```

Clicking on "A" will take me to the list of names starting with "A".

Does anyone know name of this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fantastic script that can help with what you're looking for:

http://www.ihwy.com/labs/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx

DEMO:
http://www.ihwy.com/labs/Demos/Current/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx

credit to iHwy,inc for creating it :)